# Horizontal and vertical bootstrap navbars not working correctly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried including two bootstrap menus, one vertical and one horizontal in my webpage, but the layout was destroyed. Is there any solution for this? 
This is my horizontal menu code:

```
<html lang="en"><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>

    <!-- Fixed navbar -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="home.php">Company</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="home.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i><span>&nbsp;Home</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="order.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i><span>&nbsp;Order</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="cart.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></i><span>&nbsp;Cart</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="contactus.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i><span>&nbsp;Contact Us</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="about.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i><span>&nbsp;About Us</span></a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="register.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-registration-mark"></i><span>&nbsp;Register</span></a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="login.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i><span>&nbsp;Login</span></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

and this is my vertical menu code.

```
<html lang="en"><head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="generator" content="Bootply">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- CSS code from Bootply.com editor -->

        <style type="text/css">
            @media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-collapse {
    height: auto;
    border-top: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    max-height: none;
    padding-left:0;
    padding-right:0;
  }
  .navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: block !important;
    width: auto !important;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    overflow: visible !important;
  }
  .navbar-collapse.in {
    overflow-x: visible;
  }

.navbar
{
    max-width:200px;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top:200px;
}   

.navbar-nav,
.navbar-nav > li,
.navbar-left,
.navbar-right,
.navbar-header
{float:none !important;}

.navbar-right .dropdown-menu {left:0;right:auto;}
.navbar-collapse .navbar-nav.navbar-right:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-top:200;
}
}
        </style>
    </head>

    <!-- HTML code from Bootply.com editor -->

    <body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">


  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="breads.php">Breads</a></li>
      <li><a href="cupcakes.php">Cupcakes</a></li>
      <li><a href="pies.php">Pies</a></li>
      <li><a href="pastas.php">Pastas</a></li>
      <li><a href="desserts.php">Desserts</a></li>
      <li><a href="caters.php">Caters</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>


</body></html>
```

And then I want to include it here.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Categories - Breads</title>

</head>
<body>

<?php include_once("hor_menu.php");?>   
<?php include_once("vert_menu.php");?>

</body>
</html>
```

Is it possible to include both files without destroying the layout?

Comment: You'll need to post your code if you want help

Comment: @Jonathon I included the codes. thanks.

Comment: You've got 2 separate complete HTML files and you are trying to include them both within another HTML file? They are all essentially separate pages and they shouldn't be combined like that

Comment: @Jonathon but, how should I combine it then?
sorry, I'm just a beginner in web programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (I've not tested it)

```
<html lang="en"><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <style type="text/css">
            @media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-collapse {
    height: auto;
    border-top: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    max-height: none;
    padding-left:0;
    padding-right:0;
  }
  .navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: block !important;
    width: auto !important;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    overflow: visible !important;
  }
  .navbar-collapse.in {
    overflow-x: visible;
  }

.navbar
{
    max-width:200px;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top:200px;
}   

.navbar-nav,
.navbar-nav > li,
.navbar-left,
.navbar-right,
.navbar-header
{float:none !important;}

.navbar-right .dropdown-menu {left:0;right:auto;}
.navbar-collapse .navbar-nav.navbar-right:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-top:200;
}
}
        </style>

  </head>

  <body>

    <!-- Fixed navbar -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="home.php">Company</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="home.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i><span>&nbsp;Home</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="order.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i><span>&nbsp;Order</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="cart.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></i><span>&nbsp;Cart</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="contactus.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i><span>&nbsp;Contact Us</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="about.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i><span>&nbsp;About Us</span></a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="register.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-registration-mark"></i><span>&nbsp;Register</span></a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="login.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i><span>&nbsp;Login</span></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </div>


<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">


  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="breads.php">Breads</a></li>
      <li><a href="cupcakes.php">Cupcakes</a></li>
      <li><a href="pies.php">Pies</a></li>
      <li><a href="pastas.php">Pastas</a></li>
      <li><a href="desserts.php">Desserts</a></li>
      <li><a href="caters.php">Caters</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>




    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```